# How to keep quest items

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have gotten the skeleton key in skyrim on Xbox and want to know if it can be kept or cloned/i do not know how to do the commands on my counsel

Comment: Also if it can be cloned how do I clone other items too

Answer (score 7):

The simplest way to keep the skeleton key is to not finish the Darkness Returns quest. Doing this prevents you from completing the Thieves Guild quest line, however, once your lockpicking skill is 100, you can pick up the "Unbreakable" perk which causes your lockpicks to never break. Since the main advantage of the Skeleton Key is that it can't break, once you have this lockpicking perk, you can complete Darkness Returns (and thus finish the Thieves Guild quest line) and retain an unbreakable lockpick.

Comment: But at 100 Lock-picking, you really shouldn't be breaking more picks than you can find.

Comment: Well I thought about keeping the skeleton key but my cousin completed the quest will I was at a friends house but I still have save(currently stuck in the giant hole just before you return the key

Comment: Also I would like to keep it and complete the thieves guild

Comment: Picks are plentiful & weightless.  I think I'd actually purchased some near the beginning of my 1st game.  Now I just avoid "master" locks if I've got less than 40 picks.  (Gotta save some for later in the run...)  Before long I see that I've got "99+" picks & just stop worrying.  Lock-picking is one of my favorite skills to make "Legendary" because it's so easy to raise, the perks are pretty much pointless, and a low skill will just eat a few more picks (which by this time you have *plenty* of).